# .htaccess working locally, but not on 1and1 server

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I uploaded the current .htaccess file to a 1and1 server (actually 1und1.de, but I guess it's the same) and I'm geting a 500 Internal Server Error.

```
Options -MultiViews 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /lammkontor

RewriteRule ^categories/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=category.php&cat_url=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/?$ index.php?url=product.php&cat_url=$1&prod_url=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^categories/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/recipes?$ index.php?url=recipes.php&cat_url=$1&prod_url=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

This .htaccess works perfectly on my local MAMP server.

When I test the CGI-Monitor in the control-center with an example file I get 
`- cgi: File not present or has invalid modes
(no output)`

The only file working now is index.php

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Look at your apache logs and it will usually tell you more specifics about why there is a 500 error.

Comment: 1. Make sure the file is actually there by visiting the file url. 2. Make sure the file has correct permission. If 1 works, then 2 should be fine.

Comment: Try removing `Options -MultiViews` and see if you still get the 500 error, then it doesn't get 500, there could be a config difference in your httpd.conf

Comment: RewriteBase /lammkontor ? Your test site is in this subfolder?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually I solved my problem adding a slash to the beginning of every Rewrite Rule, like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)/?$ /index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

instead of

```
RewriteRule ^(.+\.php)/?$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

By default apache's `htaccess` rights are off or limited depending on your host. 
I *suspect* its your `Options -MultiViews` causing the error.

Check your `httpd.conf` and check that `MultiViews` is allowed like below.

```
<Directory />
  Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride Indexes Options=All,MultiViews
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a slash before the url. eg /index.php instead of index.php at the end of the rule